# How do I make server slash commands usable on every server my discord bot is, And how do I delete every registered command before readding new ones?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I tried to make discord bot that stores deleted and edited messages
in json file or database.
And to do that i thouth of using slash commands but i have some issues
**
that documentation(discord.js) doesn't eaven show how to fix
**

Can someone help?

[commands from tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvaCc.png)

code snaps:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBXex.png)

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');

const commands = [
  {
    name: 'get',
    description: 'gets message',
  },
];

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Registering slash commands...');
    await rest.put(
      Routes.applicationGuildCommands(
        process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        process.env.GUILD_ID
      ),
      { body: [] }
    );

    console.log('Slash commands were registered successfully!');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`There was an error: ${error}`);
  }
})();
```

What did you try and what were you expecting? - to understand objects from tutorial code and I thouth I whould learn them easly this way.

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet the commands variable is never actually included meaning the commands would never be deployed, so I've fixed that in this answer.

To deploy global commands instead of guild commands use the `Routes.applicationCommands` method:

```js
await rest.put(
  Routes.applicationCommands(
    process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  ), { body: commands }
);
```

Note how I have changed the method name from `applicationGuildCommands` to `applicationCommands` and also removed the guild ID environmental variable as it is not necessary for global deployments.

If you would like to delete all preexisting slash commands before deploying:

For a singular guild:

```js
rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: [] })
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully deleted all guild commands.'))
    .catch(console.error);
```

For global commands:

```js
rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(clientId), { body: [] })
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully deleted all application commands.'))
    .catch(console.error);
```

Note that it is not recommended to delete all slash commands and rather delete or update singular commands by ID, [read more on that here](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/deleting-commands.html#deleting-specific-commands)